# How to delay display of Bootstrap 3 modal after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to delay the display of a Bootstrap modal after the user has clicked on a trigger button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Looking at the Bootstrap 3 documentation I can see there is a `show` event that can be hooked to but am not sure how to introduce a 3 second delay before the modal appears on screen. Hoping someone can help?

Ref:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Out of curiosity, why on earth would you want to?

Comment: I have easy solution > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394729/showing-bootstrap-modal-after-a-delay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can delay the click of the trigger button, then activate the modal directly:

```
$('[data-toggle=modal]').on('click', function (e) {
    var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
    $target.data('triggered',true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($target.data('triggered')) {
            $target.modal('show')
                .data('triggered',false); // prevents multiple clicks from reopening
        };
    }, 3000); // milliseconds
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/H6UM4/

Comment: Thanks for this, I just tried the jsfiddle. The modal doesn't display. I just seem to get a grey overlay after the 3 second delay

Comment: Maybe the delay should be put on the click (trigger) event rather than the `show.bs.modal` event?

Comment: Ah yes, just got your edit. See you're already on to that. I'll give the new code a try

Comment: Only problem: if you click it twice before the modal shows, then close the modal immediately, the second click opens the modal again. Not sure what the best way around that would be.

Comment: Solved! Updating answer.

Comment: I think i have easy solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394729/showing-bootstrap-modal-after-a-delay

Answer (score 5):

Use `.on()` to hook into the event:

```
var isFirstShowCall = false;

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    isFirstShowCall = !isFirstShowCall; // Prevents an endless recursive call
    if(isFirstShowCall) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent immediate opening
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }, 3000)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G9XeA/

Comment: Updated my answer, although using the click event is much more elegant

Comment: Thanks ReeceJHayward - this is worthy of being an accepted answer but I can only accept 1 so i'll +1 this solution.

Comment: I like how this toggles the Boolean flag one way on the initial click, and back again on the `.modal('show')` call. However, this means that if the user clicks the button twice in rapid succession, the modal shows up immediately after the second click.

Comment: If this was in my app I'd probably call that a "feature" (Edit: on second thought, it's quite buggy at handling multiple clicks)

Comment: In my case the double click doesn't matter because the trigger button is in a dropdown. On 1st click, the dropdown closes before the user has the chance to click again.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
}, 5000)
```

For demo I used 5000 mini seconds. You can used it  as per your need...

Answer (score 0):

If any of those above method does't work, give this method a try. It will work perfectly.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }, 2000);
});
```