# Showing Bootstrap modal after a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I show a Bootstrap modal after 2 seconds without triggering the modal via a button?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Following Link has a detailed description of how to implement it. http://www.5balloons.info/bootstrap-modal-pop-up-show-after-a-delay-for-ads-or-email-subscription/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assume you have loaded the bootstrap js file, Use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) Event. Also take a look on [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks, its working

Answer (score 13):

```
$(window).load(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }, 2000);
});
```

This is how I use it when I prefer it to automatically trigger on page load.