# Loading Bootstrap modal after delay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a cratejoy site, and my client needs a modal to popup after a set amount of time. I added the modal and when I use this it works fine:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

But when I try to use either of these answers from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394729/showing-bootstrap-modal-after-a-delay), it get a *Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function* error and the modal does not popup. You can see it not working [here](http://www.becoming1percent.com/).

Comment: Did you have the bootstrap.js file on your `html`. Also you need to put this script at the end of your page and wrap it in a $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: I wrapped it in that and it still didn't work. And the modal shows up if I dont use setTimeout() regardless if I wrap it in that or not.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to have link to bootstrap.js in your page and loaded after jquery.

Second you have to place the script in a script tag before the end `body` tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

In order to delay the modal you can do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}, 5000)
```

Comment: typo in setTimeout

Comment: @charlietfl Woops. Thanks :)

Comment: That didn't work either even if I tried with setTimeout

Comment: @charlietfl has already pointed out that you have multiple version of jquery loaded, and you must take care that bootstrap.js is loaded after jquery. YOu have already corrected this? There is nothing magic in the snipped I have posted. It is just a standard way to do this.

Comment: @MarcHoover you have placed the script outside the end body tag. You need to place it inside the body tag.

Comment: @Franco Sorry I read that as after the body tag. And as for the multiple jquery versions, that it something that cratejoy did for some unknown reason - if it doesn't work, it looks like i'm not going to be able to do this, as if I remove one jquery it throws even more errors. I have the script as the last thing before the body tag, so it looks like its because of the multiple jquery versions.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but my browser crashed. I have seen on your site that the modal shows properly but you have not added the timeout yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple versions of jQuery being loaded

Apart from the obvious version with it's own script tag your main.js file also includes it.

Since it loads after bootstrap.js it overwrites the whole jQuery object and removes reference to bootstrap in original version. That is why you get the error shown

Choose which version of jQuery you want to use and remove the other.

Make sure boostrap.js loads after the selected choice

Comment: I don't know why cratejoy did that - and I can't remove any of those jQuery links or it throws even more errors. It looks like I wont be doing this.

Comment: rules are simple...jquery must load before plugins like bootstrap and any code that uses jquery must come after that