# Delay opening modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wanna do this:
When you click on a button site goes to a specified section and then a bootstrap modal is opening.

I tried just delay opening a modal, in that way sites would goes down to specified section and then modal is displaying. I tried did is with setTimeout function, but the problem is that it isnt working.

```
$('[data-toggle=modal]').on('click', function (e) {
var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
$target.data('triggered',true);
setTimeout(function() {
    if ($target.data('triggered')) {
        $target.modal('show')
            .data('triggered',false); //
    };
}, 2000); // milliseconds
return false;
});
```

Button looks like this:

```
<div type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#succes-modal"><a href='#your-succes' rel="m_PageScroll2id"><div class='home_slider_btn'>READ MORE</div></a></div>
```

I used that script but the modal is opening right after you click on a button. I dont know why that function isnt working properly.

Do you have some ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: make a fiddle for your code. here https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696456/how-to-delay-display-of-bootstrap-3-modal-after-click/23696636#23696636
You copied from this place. Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, a tried some others solutions including second script from that thread. It doesnt work...

Answer (score 1):

By default, all elements with `data-toggle="modal"` are bound in `bootstrap.js`, so replace it with something else. such as `data-toggle="modal-delay"`

```
<a data-toggle="modal-delay" data-target="#succes-modal"></a>
```

HTML

```
$('[data-toggle=modal-delay]').on('click', function (e) {
      var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
      $target.data('triggered',true);
      setTimeout(function() {
            if ($target.data('triggered')) {
                 $target.modal('show')
                 .data('triggered',false); //
            };
      }, 2000); // milliseconds
      return false;
});
```

OR

use the `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Thanks! Its almost working. Its all good, but the problem is that it's working by the first click, when you close a modal and try to open it once again the it dont displaying

Comment: @Marcin324, could please forward me the link? or create a fiddle that re-produces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Per Twitter Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes), when element with `data-toggle="modal"` is clicked, the modal dialog is launched immediately.

If you want to have a custom behavior, remove the `data-toggle` attribute from your button and use a different selector.